# How to remove sourcemap in reactjs [webpack5]

Tags: reactjs

No working for value :

```
 devtools = 'none'
```

LOG:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```